# upper bound for the sum of absolute value of eigenvalues, the corresponding matrix is real symmetric with diagonal 0's

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

$A=\left(a_{ij}\right)\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ s.t.
$a_{ij}=a_{ji}=\begin{cases}0,&i=j\\0\lor 1&i\ne j\end{cases}$

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$

I want to find an upper bound of $\sum |\lambda_j|$.

It will be best if someone can give an upper bound $\frac{1}{2}n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ roughly when n is large enough.(or even less than it)

Comment: You are maximising the nuclear norm/trace norm of $A$. I haven't any proof, but I guess that the maximum value is $2(n-1)$, which is attained at $A=E-I$, where $E$ is the all-one matrix.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks! I haven't heard about nuclear norm before. It is really an important information. I searched "nuclear norm, adjacency matrix" and found that Koolen and Moulton have proved it has an upper bound $\frac{1}{2}n(\sqrt{n}+1)$. The equality holds if and only if the corresponding graph is a specific family of strongly regular graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there are $m$ nonzero entries in $A$. Then using Cauchy-Schwartz and the fact that here $m=\text{Tr}(A^2)=\sum_{i =1}^n \lambda_i^2$, you get the bound:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i =1}^n \vert\lambda_i\vert \leq \bigg(n\sum_{i =1}^n \lambda_i^2\bigg)^{1/2}=(nm)^{1/2}. 
\end{equation}

This doesn’t really use the fact the diagonal is zero. For the matrix with all off-diagonals equal to 1, this is off by a roughly $\sqrt{n}$ factor, so I’m not sure how good it is. If you allow the off-diagonal entries to be $-1$ as well, this bound is actually tight, as shown by Hao Huang using a signing of the adjacency matrix of the Boolean hypercube in the recent resolution of the Sensitivity Conjecture.

Comment: thanks! I just found that I need a upper bound roughly $\frac{1}{2} n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ , this seems not small enough...I will edit this question later. But the $-1$ part you mentioned is very interesting.

Comment: @AlmostTrivial how important is the $1/2$? That’s essentially all that is being lost here, and this gives sharper results for sparse matrices. I agree with the comment above though that the example I gave seems worst case. I’d recommend trying high-rank bipartite graphs; their spectrum is symmetric so leads to larger nuclear norms.

Comment: Actually it is a homework in my class, I am required to prove the $\frac{1}{2}$. I found that Koolen and Moulton have proved it has an upper bound $\frac{1}{2}n(\sqrt{n}+1)$. Also,https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282844351_Beyond_graph_energy_Norms_of_graphs_and_matrices  in this article, the author proved it very simply by constructing a matrix allowed $−1$ and using the tight bound you said!